# YoutubePlayer don't work in android 8 and "android system webview has stopped" appear however in android 12 it work fine

Tags: android, kotlin

this is the function that show the youtube video :

```
    private fun initYoutubePlayer(youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer) {
        val defaultPlayerUiController =
            DefaultPlayerUiController(binding.youtubePlayerView, youTubePlayer)

        defaultPlayerUiController.showCurrentTime(false)
        defaultPlayerUiController.showSeekBar(false)
        defaultPlayerUiController.showDuration(false)
        defaultPlayerUiController.showYouTubeButton(false)
        defaultPlayerUiController.showFullscreenButton(false)
        defaultPlayerUiController.showPlayPauseButton(false)
        binding.youtubePlayerView.setCustomPlayerUi(defaultPlayerUiController.rootView)
    }
```

Comment: I think that the problem isn't related to code hower the problem in Android System WebView app o_O

Comment: If there's no useful info in logcat, you could try following these instructions to debug the Webview in Chrome on a desktop machine, and see if it gives you any useful errors: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: @cactustictacs the in info in logcat when the crash appear